# How to test a method that retries on an Uni?

Tags: java, mockito, quarkus, mutiny

I'm using Quarkus, RESTEasy and Mutiny.

I have a method that calls a REST client and retries on failures.

```java
class MyService {
  private MyRestClient restClient;

  public Uni<Response> fetchData() {
        return restClient.fetchData()
                .onFailure().retry().withBackOff(Duration.ofMillis(100), Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                .atMost(5);
    }
}
```

I want to test that it retries correctly, so I wrote this test:

```java
@Test
public void shouldRetry() { 
    Mockito.when(restClient.fetchData())
        .thenReturn(
            Uni.createFrom().failure(new RuntimeException("Failed to fetch data")),
            Uni.createFrom().item(Response.ok().build())
        );

        assertDoesNotThrow(() -> myService.fetchData().await().indefinetely());

        Mockito.verify(restClient, Mockito.times(2)).fetchData();
    }
```

However, the test is failing on the "does not throw" assertion. The method retries correctly, but I believe it's not triggering a new `fetchData` call. It seems that it is running against the very same `Uni` that was mocked to return an exception, rather than getting the new one which is supposed to return an OK Response. Thus, it keeps getting an error repeatedly. It's either this or I'm using Mockito the wrong way.

It keeps retrying up to the fifth attempt, when it throws `IllegalStateException`:

```
Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Retries exhausted: 5/5
```

Does anybody know how I can fix this test to get a proper result? Or maybe the problem lies in the actual code under test?

Comment: This blog post was somewhat clarifying: https://quarkus.io/blog/uni-retry/ — it explains that retry works by resubscribing. Thus, only mocking the RestClient's returned Uni won't work, I'll have to mock the Uni's subscribe method or something... maybe it's easier to mock the HTTP layer.

Comment: The only real way to see this would be to do a real test and use something like Wiremock for simulating the downstream service

Answer (score -1):

See this [link](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/2.5.1/guides/testing/). It's from the official Mutiny site.